# Android REST HTTP receiving {"status":"400","error":"Bad Request"} when execute

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, httprequest, httpclient

This is the following android code on asynctask to fetch the data from the website. I also provide it with username, password and a params. The result is  {"status":"400","error":"Bad Request"}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
List<NameValuePair> params;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    String username = "usay";
    String password = "isc00l";
     InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb;
     JSONObject jObj = null;
     String json = "";
    String result="";
    String unp = username+":"+password;
    params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token","6eebeac3dd1dc9c97a06985b6480471211a777b39aa4d0e03747ce6acc4a3369"));
    try {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(domain.trim()+"/qhms/wse_hmlogin.php?loginid="+user.trim()+"&logpass="+pass.trim());
        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(domain+"/qhms/wse_hmlogin.php?loginid="+user+"&logpass="+pass);
        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://svv.in.net/service/index.php?user=Customer&pass=cus&des=rtr%20r%20rtr%20trtrt");
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www-staging.usay.co/app/surveys.json");
        //if(params !=null){
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
       // }
        // httppost.setHeader( "Authorization","Basic "+"admin:admin");
        String encoded_login = Base64.encodeToString(unp.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        httppost.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded_login));

        System.out.println("URL="+httppost.toString());

        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://quantumr.info/qrms/call_service/wse_getitem.php?compkey=astres1312");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line = "0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    Log.e("result",result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Who told you to do the request in this way?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this request, I have use it with other url and it is able receive the value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to receive the String using an alternative method

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www-staging.usay.co/app/surveys.json?access_token=6eebeac3dd1dc9c97a06985b6480471211a777b39aa4d0e03747ce6acc4a3369");
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("usay", "isc00l"),
                "UTF-8", false));
try
{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    inputStream = responseEntity.getContent();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

    String line = "0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
    }
    inputStream.close();
    result = stringBuilder.toString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
Log.e("result",result);
return result;
```